# IdentityServer4 in NetCore, tokens lost on restart

Tags: authentication, security, token, identityserver4, identity

I am facing an issue with IdentityServer4. Whenever I restart the server, the tokens get deleted from memory and the users have to re-identify themselves.
I need these tokens to persist and not get lost on server reboot or crash...
I have been informed that there is a way to store them on disk, but I am unsure of how to do it. Can someone please assist me with the configuration required to achieve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean when you restart IdentityServer or when you restart the client applications?

Comment: i'm restart IdentityServer have any way to persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time it has been discovered what caused the problem of the Jwt tokens, which are not the reference tokens, no problems have been detected in the persistence in the database, what has been seen is that the cryptographic key used by these self-contained tokens is lost in each server restart;
This is due to an implementation error and leaving "UseTemporarySigningKeyForDevelopment" option active, the problem will be solved using a .PFX file in the options "UseSigningCertificatePfxFile" and "UseValidationCertificatePfxFile", and thus we ensure that when restarting the machine the cryptographic key is maintained and thus the tokens generated before the restart are still validated correctly.

Answer (score -1):

To review the documentation [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/data/) on how to properly persist the grants and operational data to a database.

Many uses a database to store the operational data but IdentityServer supports many different persistence alternatives.

It is also recommended to ensure you have properly configured the Data Protection API, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for details.

Finally, you also need to have a strategy around your signing keys, see this [link](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/data/operational/keys/) for details.